# Two fast machines vs one slow machine - Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I am trying to find out what the probability is that my order is finished earlier when I put it through one machine that on Poisson distribution finished lambda = 3 orders per hour vs. two machines that have lambda1 = 8 per hour and lambda2 = 10 per hour but in this scenario you have to pass through both machines subsequently!

I understand that on option 1 my expected time is 1/3 of an hour but I am struggling how to find the probability that this is quicker than by using the two faster machines that have to be used both after each other. Especially how exactly I use the Poisson distribution here with the question of "probability that option 1 is faster".

Comment: In the subsequent machine case, which machine is first?

Comment: You might consider using the exponential distribution instead of Poisson.

Comment: @awkward won't the order of the subsequent machines matter, in your opinion?

Comment: The order of the two alternative machines doesn't matter.  The sums of the two times have the same distribution regardless of the order because. $x+y=y+x$.